# How do I shut down Windows 10 completely at inactitivy?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, energy-saving

I would like to make it so that after 3 minutes of inactivity (no touch on a Windows table), the monitor is turned off.

This works by setting "Turn off monitor after 3 minutes".

Then, after 1 hour, the computer should shut down completely.
However, I only see "Turn off monitor after..." and "Go to stand-by after".
I have not found an option like "Shut down completely after...".

What am I missing, and how could I do what I want?

Thank you!

Comment: The option you are looking for is suspending your machine.  Suspending is an extremely low power state that modern machines support.  You would be better off just waiting longer for your display to be turned off and go directly into a suspended state.  Waking out of a hybrid shutdown is seconds with the right hardware.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Shut your computer down "completely" you can create a task as such:

1. Open task manager > Actions > Create a task
2. Give it a name, for eg. shutdown
3. Add a trigger, and select "at log on" for the drop down given for when to begin the task

[image]

4. Add an action:

[image]

5. Under the "conditions tab", select `start the task only if the computer is idle for` and `restart if the idle state resumes`. Set the time as per your own requirement.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. My computer turns off the monitor, but it does not call shutdown.exe after the specified time. My computer is not attached the AC. What else could I check?

Comment: @SkyCaver I'm sorry, I missed that you need to check the "run with elevated privellages" checkbox as well, in the first tab.